# Eclipse Tomcat publish not working

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, tomcat

I am a newbie in web applications.

I created a spring web project using Tomcat as my application server, which was running fine.

I made a few changes to the WEB-INF folder(added new .html files etc), which got published once, but since then no changes of mine are getting published.

Somehow, Tomcat/Eclipse seems to be retaining a particular version of my WEB-INF, and every time I publish, it is delpoying that version.
This is weird, becuase even if I delete a particular JSP file from my working WEB-INF directory, after i publish and do "run on Server", the files remain on my tomcat wtpwebapps folder.

I even manually deleted the JSP file from my wtpwebapps folder in my Tomcat Directory, but when I do another publish and "run o server" they magically apper back in my tomcat direcory
(even though they are no longer i my eclipse WEB-INF folder)

Someone please tell me what is missing.. I am terribly frustrated with this.

**UPDATE:**
SOLVED:
I was editing my jsp files and deleting them manually(not from eclipse). For some reason eclipse was not picking them up and not deploying them. I refreshed my eclipse folder and evrything is working now.

Thats weird! I would be glad if someone explained to me why this was happening

Comment: Can you try installing the same project on the Tomcat server without using eclipse ? Does that deploys latest changes ?

Comment: Check your server.xml on your Tomcat Server deployed on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the stuff you get published to the server webapps folder comes from the TARGET. The TARGET contents comes from your local working copy files.

Now what is likely is that your local files are not copied to target folder before publishing. I had that kind of problem.

What I do not know but what I suspect is that there is a background process that checks for modified files. If it does not find one or it is slow to find one - you may publish unupdated files from target.

**Conclusion:**

Check your target directory in your local project if unsure what you publish.

**Solution:**

Before you publish:

Menu > Project > Clean... > [X] start a build automatically > Clean.*

The downside of the above is time. It takes a while to build/clean especially when your project is big.